# Dynamic TextSize in WPF UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf, font-size, uielement

As suggested I allow all of my WPF `UIElement`s to have a dynamic size so they can be resized easily however, in `TextBlock`s I have to specify the size of the `Font`. This means when the element's size increases or decreases the Font size stays the same. Is there a way for the `Font` size to be dynamic?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting the text inside the control into a `Viewbox`:

```
<Button>
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock>Text To Resize</TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```